# Optimising generic backtracking algorithm for N Queens

Tags: java

For my N Queens problem solver, I'm currently using backtracking and I'm reaching an average of 7ms in runtime. However, I'm looking to optimize my backtracking further so that it has a better time complexity.

```
 public boolean solveQueen( int col) { 
         if(col == qColumn) {
             solveQueen(col +1);
         }
         if(col >= board.length) {  
             printBoard();
             System.out.println();
             return true; 

         }

         for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)

             if(notUnderAttack(i,col)) 
             {

                 placeQ(i,col);
                 solveQueen(col +1);

                 removeQ(i, col);  


             }

         return false;         
     }
```

As well from what I read, N queens backtracking has a time complexity of O(N!) but with my backtracking, I'm skipping a column since I'm placing a queen down first so shouldn't it be O(N!-1)?

Will appreciate any feedback that comes my way ^^

Comment: Please provide complete code so that we can advice you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question could be interpreted in two ways. Would you like to reduce the algorithmic complexity of this problem or would you like to make it run a bit faster?

**Reducing the algorithmic complexity is not going to work.** The N-Queen problem is a famous problem, millions of developers have seen it by now. In order to understand better the meaning of the expression "algorithmic complexity" I suggest reading some extra material. The preface of [this doc](https://discrete.gr/complexity/) + doing the first two exercises could be a good start.

**Making the application run a bit faster is doable.** Knowing Java more and implementing little tricks gives you an endless source of ways to reduce a few percentages of runtime. Before you even start that you should setup a reliable test-system (for example [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)) to track your progress. You can look into object allocation details, JIT, in-lining, the size of your variables, etc. Some may be a bit scary at first, but it is a fun way to learn new things.